# Pycharm в linux mint не дает создать окружение для python 3.9

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, python-3.9

При попытке выбрать интерпретатор python 3.9 и создать проект Pycharm выдает такую ошибку:

```
Error: Command '['/home/username/PycharmProjects/pythukjjjhonProject1/pythonProject5/bin/python3.9', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

И pip обновил и с окружением повозился но результат тот же
P.s помимо 3.9 стоит python 2.7 и 3.5

Comment: интересно, а почему питон ищется прямо у Вас в каталоге?

Comment: Путь до интерпретатора я вроде правильный ставил usr /local/bin/python3.9